# Redis publish memory leak?

Tags: node.js, redis

I know that there is already many questions like this, but i don't find one that fits my implementation.
I'm using redis in a Node.js env, and it feels like redis.publish is leaking some memory. I expect it to be some kind of "backpressure" thing, like seen here:
[Node redis publisher consuming too much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873102/node-redis-publisher-consuming-too-much-memory)

But to my understanding: Node needs to release that kind of pressure in a synchronous context, otherwise, the node event loop won't be called, and the GC won't be called either.

My program looks like that:

```
const websocketApi = new WebsocketApi()
const currentState = {}

websocketApi.connect()
websocketApi.on('open', () => {
  channels.map((channel) => websocketApi.subscribeChannel(channel))
})

websocketApi.on('message', (message) => {
  const ob = JSON.parse(message)

  if (currentState[ob.id]) {
    currentState[ob.id] = update(currentState[ob.id], ob.data)
  } else {
    currentState[ob.id] = ob.data
  }

  const payload = {
    channel: ob.id,
    info: currentState[ob.id],
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    type: 'newData'
  }
  // when i remove this part, the memory is stable
  redisClient.publish(payload.channel, JSON.stringify(payload))
})
// to reconnect in case of error
websocketApi.on('close', () =>
  websocketApi.connect())
```

It seems that the messages are too close from each other, so it doesn't have time to release the strings hold in the redis.publish.

Do you have any idea of what is wrong in this code ?

EDIT: More specifically, what I can observe when I do memory dumps of my application:

- The memory is staturated with string that are my Stringified JSON payloads, and "chunks" of messages that are send via Redis itself. Their ref are hold inside the redis client manly in variables called chunk.
  Some string payloads are still released, but I create them way faster.
- When I don't publish the messages via Redis, the "currentState" variable grows until a point then don't grow anymore. It obviously has a big RAM impact, but it's expected. The rest is fine and the application is stable around 400mb, and it explodes whith the redis publisher (PM2 restarts it cause it reaches max RAM capacity)
- My feeling here is that I ask redis to publish way more that it can handle, and redis doesn't have the time to finish to publish the messages. It still holds all the context, so it doesn't release anything. I may need some kind of "queue" to let redis release some context and finish publishing the messages. Is that really a possibility or am I becoming crazy ?

Basically, every loop in my program is "independent". Is it possible to have as many redis clients as I have got loops ? is it a better idea ? (IMHO, node is mono threaded, so it won't help, but it may help the V8 to better track down memory references and releasing memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redis client buffers commands if the client is not connected either because it has not yet connected or its connection fails or it fails to connect.

Make sure that you can connect to the redis server. Make sure that your program is connected to the server. I would suggest adding a listener to `redisClient.on('connect')` if that is not emitted the client never connected.

If you are connected, the client shouldn't be buffering but to make the problem appear sooner disable the offline queue, pass the option `enable_offline_queue: false` to `createClient` this will cause attempts to send commands when not connected fail.

You should attach an error listener to the `redisClient`: `redisClient.on('error', console.error.bind(console))`. This might yield a message as to why the client is buffering.

Comment: Yeah i know that the current state will increase until a point. When all ils initialized, an update basicaly adds nothing, only changes some values. The true leak (imho) is staying in the redis publisher: when I do some memory dump of my app, i mostly find strings that are my JSON stringify payload that are hold inside my redis client. It doesn't seems that the memory is release after that. When I delete the publish part, the memory grows until a point, then stays relativly stable.

Comment: After edit comment: This code is called when the redis client is connected, so it's probably not that. Not only the redis is connected, but i can see it's result if i listen to it's channels. I will still try to add the option enable_offline_queue: false and give it a try. I will add some details about what I can see in my memory dumps in my original post, I hope it can help.

Comment: increasing the Pub/Sub client default hard limit of 32 megabytes server side + enable_offline_queue: false seems to work immensely in my case. I've never been so light. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Convert the message u are sending to a Buffer and send it like that to the redis pub channel instead of a normal string. It really helps a lot

`Buffer.from(str, 'utf-8')`